# I do not understand somethings in 'Argument Initialization' in <Inside The C++ Object Model>

Tags: c++

In the book  Chapter 2.2 Argument Initialization

When we call a function which have a class object argument, The compiler will construct a temp object by copy constructor, use the temp argument to call the function, and change the argument from class object to class reference, like  this :

```
void foo( X x0 );   
X xx;   
foo(xx);  
------------------ 
X __temp0;  
__temp0.X::X(xx);   
void foo( X& x0 );  
foo(__temp0);
```

I don't understand why compiler should change the argument from class X object to class X reference?

Comment: that is plain wrong.

Comment: Wait does it says that the compiler will change the argument to reference or that you should change the argument to reference?

Comment: `X` could be arbitrarily large, and there's only so much data you can stuff into CPU registers. So the calling convention for passing a large argument by value is to create a temporary on the stack, and pass a pointer to that temporary. Similarly, when a function returns a class object by value, the convention is as follows: the caller allocates space on the stack sufficient to hold the result, and passes a pointer to that space. The function then constructs its return value into that space.

Comment: Does the book say that you should pass by reference instead? The only reason to pass by (non-const) reference instead of by-value is if the function you're calling wants to modify the original object.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik: If object size is the __only__ concern, then the correct thing to do is to pass it via __const__ reference.

Comment: @antred This is not about how you should write your code - it's about how the compiler implements the code you've already written. That's the topic of this particular book.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik: Oh, ok. But in that case the answer should be, who cares?? Internally the compiler may do whatever the heck it wants, so long as the end result is behavior as defined by the C++ standard.

Comment: @antred : The OP cares, obviously, as well as the author(s) of the book that described it in the first place.

Comment: @antred Well, evidently, some people care enough to write this book, and others enough to buy and read it. In the same way that most people are happy just using the controls of their car, but some are curious about how the engine actually works under the hood.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik: Ok, so I worded my comment poorly. My point was not that I don't care but that it's impossible to make a general statement because every compiler may handle that differently.

Comment: @antred This is usually defined by the platform ABI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Implementation details for x86-64 follow. Your architecture may vary.

This is because parameters are mostly passed in registers and there is not enough space to fit objects there. Therefore the compiler passes temporary references instead. It does not change the behavior at all and therefore is legal by the C++ standard.